# Add time from column to date-column on condition from third column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe df that contains (among others) three columns: `day`, `timeTo` and `goesOverDateBoundary`.

`day` is a date-variable while `timeTo` is a string in the format %H:%M (ex: 18:00). `goesOverDateBoundary` is a boolean.

I'd like to "add" `timeTo` to `day`  where `goesOverDateBoundary` is `False` and I'd like to add `timeTo` to `day` + 1 where `goesOverDateBoundary` is `True`.

With "add" I mean that day `31-12-2020` and timeTo `18:00` becomes a datetime object `31-12-2010 18:00`. Likewise if  `goesOverDateBoundary` is `True` the resulting object should be `01-01-2021 18:00`.

I considered iterating over the rows in my dataframe but it says [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16476924/how-to-iterate-over-rows-in-a-dataframe-in-pandas) that you should "never" do that.

Example data:

```
+------------+--------+----------------------+------------------+
|    day     | timeTo | goesOverDateBoundary |   resultIdLike   |
+------------+--------+----------------------+------------------+
| 31-12-2020 | 18:00  |                    0 | 31-12-2020 18:00 |
| 31-12-2020 | 18:00  |                    1 | 01-01-2021 18:00 |
| 10-09-2020 | 03:00  |                    0 | 10-09-2020 03:00 |
| 10-09-2020 | 03:00  |                    1 | 11-09-2020 03:00 |
+------------+--------+----------------------+------------------+
```

Comment: Can yo uadd some data sample, 2-3 rows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert column to datetimes by [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) and times to timedeltas by [`to_timedelta`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_timedelta.html), sum and in [`Series.mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html) add 1 day with mask by convert column `goesOverDateBoundary` to boolean for `1->True` and `0->False` mapping:

```
df['day'] = pd.to_datetime(df['day'], dayfirst=True)
df['timeTo'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['timeTo'] + ':00')

s = df['day'] + df['timeTo']
df['new'] = s.mask(df['goesOverDateBoundary'].astype(bool), s + pd.Timedelta(1, unit='d'))

print (df)
         day          timeTo  goesOverDateBoundary      resultIdLike  \
0 2020-12-31 0 days 18:00:00                     0  31-12-2020 18:00   
1 2020-12-31 0 days 18:00:00                     1  01-01-2021 18:00   
2 2020-09-10 0 days 03:00:00                     0  10-09-2020 03:00   
3 2020-09-10 0 days 03:00:00                     1  11-09-2020 03:00   

                  new  
0 2020-12-31 18:00:00  
1 2021-01-01 18:00:00  
2 2020-09-10 03:00:00  
3 2020-09-11 03:00:00
```

Alternative if need original `timeTo` column:

```
df['day'] = pd.to_datetime(df['day'], dayfirst=True)
td = pd.to_timedelta(df['timeTo'] + ':00')

s = df['day'] + td
df['new'] = s.mask(df['goesOverDateBoundary'].astype(bool), s + pd.Timedelta(1, unit='d'))

print (df)
         day timeTo  goesOverDateBoundary      resultIdLike  \
0 2020-12-31  18:00                     0  31-12-2020 18:00   
1 2020-12-31  18:00                     1  01-01-2021 18:00   
2 2020-09-10  03:00                     0  10-09-2020 03:00   
3 2020-09-10  03:00                     1  11-09-2020 03:00   

                  new  
0 2020-12-31 18:00:00  
1 2021-01-01 18:00:00  
2 2020-09-10 03:00:00  
3 2020-09-11 03:00:00
```